# Add the MFMessageComposerViewController to the main view

Tags: ios, view, iad, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

is it possible to show the MFMessageComposerViewController in specified area in the main view. In other words, when i click to send a message i want to display my messageViewController inside my viewController (in order to keep the user watching the iAD banner for exemple).

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. The MFMessageComposerViewController must be shown modally.

"After configuring initial values, present the view controller modally using the presentModalViewController:animated: method. When done, dismiss it using the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: method."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html